# Setting aliased variables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, alias

I have the following T-SQL code from SQL Server Management Studio 2005:

```
UPDATE O
SET DATAREVISIONTYPE = 'Modify', O.OriginalUserID = OriginalUserID, O.EmployeeBirthdate = EmployeeBirthdate, O.User_ID = User_ID
FROM LRN_Upload_Prep as O
WHERE DATAREVISIONTYPE = 'Add' AND
(SELECT COUNT([OriginalUserId]) FROM Lrn_Upload_Prep WHERE DataRevisionType = 'Transfer' AND FirstName = O.FirstName 
AND LastName = O.LastName AND EmployeeEmailAddress = O.EmployeeEmailAddress AND LEFT(EmployeeBirthdate, 4) = O.EmployeeBirthdate)> 0
```

I can not figure out how to modify the data in the SET using alias (O.OriginalUserID = OriginalUserID, O.EmployeeBirthdate = EmployeeBirthdate, O.User_ID = User_ID) as my understanding is that the alias hasn't been declared yet. I looked into wrapping the part that declares the alias in a CTE thinking maybe that would work, but to no avail. Any fix, or suggestion on what to research would be fantastic, thanks!

Comment: You only need an alias if you are joining to another table.  That doesn't appear to be the case here.

Comment: Have you tried using the CTE inside the SET? That's what I'd try.

Comment: And what are you trying to update your columns with? Right now you are updating o.OriginalUserID with itself. OriginalUserID is also o. - you don't  have other tables in the query

Comment: It is supposed to be comparing all the values in LRN_Upload_Prep to a different instance of LRN_Upload_Prep. Basically, Checking to see if any records meet the criteria in the table already, and then updating the new record with some of the information of the existing record.